# How to connect web url in iphone application development?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iphone application.I have 6 uiimages in a view.fifth image is facebook and sixth one is twiter.Under images,Iplaced two roundrectbuttons named as click5 and click6. My requirement is,when i click on those images,I have to go to login pages of facebook and twitter.how can i do this?can anyone send me sample example and explain it detai?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the user to the website using Safari, you invoke the `openURL:` method in the `UIApplication` class, like this:

```
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
```

When assigning a button to an action, you use the `UIButton`'s `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, providing an event handler as action. Say you're setting this up in `viewDidLoad`, it might look like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [myButton addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(btnClicked:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

/**
 * Click/tap event handler for some buttons
 */
- (IBAction) btnClicked:(id)sender {

    // Check which button was pressed.
    if (sender == self.click5) {
        // ...
    }
    else if (sender == self.click6) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know the very easiest way to do this? With the free 3rd party component [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/). It wraps the Facebook and Twitter (and several other social network) APIs to literally make it a three-line deal to post things.

I used it for the first time in the last app I built and I was SHOCKED at how easy to use it was.

Comment: Here's their "how to use" page. Plenty of sample code.  The thing to notice is just how LITTLE code it takes to get this module working. http://getsharekit.com/install/